# Three beginner clarifications about Cribbage

Tags: cribbage

I started playing Cribbage on my phone 2 days ago and want to play with my friends, so I have some questions:

1. How do you determine who leads the next hand? I know the after the deal, the Pone leads, but after that, who leads?
2. After scoring a play, does each player take back their cards so that they can score their hands later?
3. Are cards shuffled every time the dealer changes?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Generally it would be better to split your questions up so that each one can be answered individually.  Not everyone who knows the answer to one question will be able to answer all three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The non-dealer leads the play for each hand.  If either player is unable to play a card without breaking 31, he calls "Go" after which the opposing player plays any other cards in his hand that are playable.  The player who called "Go" then leads the next play, starting at zero. During the show, when the hands are scored, the non-dealer also leads.
2. During the play, each player places his own cards face up in front of himself, calling out the current total of played cards.  The cards in each players hand remain separate at all times so the hand may be scored at the end.
3. The cards are shuffled with every deal.

These rules are based on the standard two player game.  For three players, the game is played clockwise with the player to the dealer's left leading the play and the show for each hand, and the player to the left of the last person to play a card leading after a "Go".

Comment: Just to double check, if 31 is reached then there is no change in lead.

Comment: If 31 is reached, play just alternates like normal.

Comment: @goldPseudo has done a good job of covering all of the rules questions here.  I would just add one more thing I've done just as a personal practice, regarding #2:  At the end of a round of play (31 is reached, or neither player can add any further) I generally turn my played cards face-down before the next round begins.  This helps to avoid confusion between cards played in different rounds.  However, do be careful to keep these cards away from the crib.